# Binding failure on MVC with a composited model to a simple model on postback

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, data-binding

I have a view in an MVC app that takes in a Model made up of a composition of other classes to display all the data I want. This works well but on post back I want to only return the values I need to complete the action in a simpler class specific for the task.

The view model example:

```
Public Class ManageEmployeeViewData
    Inherits BaseViewData


    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property CompanyId As Integer
    Public Property NewTaxCode As ManageTaxCodeUpdateModel
End Class

Public Class ManageTaxCodeUpdateModel

    Public EmployeeID As Integer
    Public TaxCode As String
    Public EffectiveDate As Date
End Class
```

The view example:

```
<form action="@Url.Action("UpdateTaxCode")" method="post">
    @Html.HiddenFor(Function(f) f.NewTaxCode.EmployeeID)
    @Html.EditorRowFor(Function(f) f.NewTaxCode.TaxCode)
    @Html.EditorFor(Function(f) f.NewTaxCode.EffectiveDate)
    <button type="submit" class=" btn save"><span class="icon"></span>Save</button>
</form>
```

The controller action for the postback:

```
<HttpPost()>
Function UpdateTaxCode(<Bind(Prefix:="NewTaxCode")> ByVal model As ManageTaxCodeUpdateModel) As ActionResult
    Dim empSvc = ObjectFactory.GetInstance(Of IEmployeeService)()
    Dim employee = empSvc.GetEmployee(model.EmployeeID)
    Return (RedirectToAction("Edit", New With {.Id = model.EmployeeID}))
End Function
```

Example of the output html:

```
<form action="/inni/Company/2220/ManageEmployees/UpdateTaxCode" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">

    <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Int32 must be a number." data-val-required="The Int32 field is required." id="NewTaxCode_EmployeeID" name="NewTaxCode.EmployeeID" type="hidden" value="6339">

    <input class="text-box single-line valid" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field DateTime must be a date." data-val-required="The DateTime field is required." id="NewTaxCode_EffectiveDate" name="NewTaxCode.EffectiveDate" type="datetime" value="01/01/0001 00:00:00">

    <input class="text-box single-line" id="NewTaxCode_TaxCode" name="NewTaxCode.TaxCode" type="text" value=""><span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="NewTaxCode.TaxCode" data-valmsg-replace="true">


    <button type="submit" class=" btn save"><span class="icon"></span>Save</button>

</form>
```

But none of the values are binded to the ManageTaxCodeUpdateModel model. Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: You can use the `[Bind(Prefix="NewTaxCode")]` attribute on your post method

Comment: That looks like it should work but still no joy. I updated my example to reflect the change you recommended

Comment: Check you html (I'm not too good with VB and I dont know what the `ByVal NewTaxCode` is). If you have controls with `name="NewTaxCode.EffectiveDate"` where `EffectiveDate` is the name of a property in `ManageTaxCodeUpdateModel`, then this should work. What `[Bind(Prefix="NewTaxCode")]` does is strip of the prefix so the instead of trying to bind `NewTaxCode.EffectiveDate` (which does not exist) it will bind to `EffectiveDate` (which does exist)

Comment: Also , one problem may be `ByVal NewTaxCode`. In c# it would be `public ActionResult UpdateTaxCode(ManageTaxCodeUpdateModel model)`. If you changed `model` to `NewTaxCode` it wont work (the name of the parameter cannot be the same as the name of a model property)

Comment: Yeah I am normally c# but inherited this VB project :(

Comment: I have updated the example code again to show some more detail.

Comment: Your html looks OK. Does it bind correctly if you use `ByVal model As ManageEmployeeViewData` (i.e. post back to the full model without the `[Bind]` attribute)?

Comment: Things bind to the parent just not the ManageTaxCodeUpdateModel model

Comment: Ok its working at last, your initial advice was correct thanks Stephen but I was missing the property keyword off the Model attributes too eg needed Public Property employeeID As Integer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66585/discussion-between-andy-stannard-and-stephen-muecke).